# How To Recover Bitlocker Drive If Password Reset Key is Lost?

Tags: windows-7, bitlocker

I've one drive locked with bit locker and i forget passowrd and lost password reset key so how to recover it?

Comment: Would this not invalidate the "encryption"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot recover your drive this drive. Because it is an encrypted drive and it is near impossible to recover without an encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable BitLocker, you can create a recovery password (48 characters) and a recovery file. If you saved the recovery file somewhere, you can still decrypt. Else you can only obtain the recovery password from the system while the OS has access to the encrypted volume.

If you lost the recovery password and are unable to access the disk at this moment, you're lost. Microsoft or HP have no options to recover your data.

> "Without the password or recovery key the data is gone."

Sources for further reading

[Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/64876-63-solved-forgot-bitlocker-password-lost-recovery)

[Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4be374ec-82d3-4901-af51-1517d21a885e/bit-locker-recovery-key-lost?forum=w7itprosecurity)